# Getting Error while executing SELECT statement in Toad for MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, toad

I am getting this error while I am trying to execute a simple SELECT statement in **Toad**

```
 MySql.Data.Types.MySqlConversionException
 Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That could mean one of these two common issues:

1) Zero dates, which are 0000-00-00 in MySQL.  MySQL allows you to store them to mark 0 dates, you can even use 0001-01-01, but not all drivers or downstream programs can handle them.  Add to the connection string

```
Allow Zero Datetime=true;
```

The other choice is explicitly removing them, something like

```
SELECT IF(DateCol='0000-00-00' OR DateCol<'1970-01-01', NULL, DateCol) as DateCol,
      Othercol1, ID ....
FROM TBL
```

2) Date formatting. For some driver/program combination, the dates are handled as strings. Explicit conversion is necessary:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DateCol, '%m/%d/%Y') as DateCol,
      Othercol1, ID ....
FROM TBL
```

Comment: Thanks Richard.!! It was a problem of Zero dates. Thanks a lot for your help.