# MySQL datetime error in Toad

Tags: mysql, linux, toad

Toad complains:

> Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime

when trying to display data in a table on a remote linux mysql database. This same issue is addressed here:

[stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088472/getting-error-while-executing-select-statement-in-toad-for-mysql)

I am trying to implement the `Allow Zero Datetime=true;` answer but am unable to find where to put the extra parameter. The Toad connection manager wizard does not seem to have anywhere to put it.